# The annotation "@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Sortable does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded

Tags: symfony, doctrine, stofdoctrineextensions

I use  "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "v1.3.0",

config.yml

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: %locale%
    orm:
        default:
            tree: ~
            timestampable: ~
            sortable: ~
            sluggable: ~
            #translatable:   ~
```

ENtity

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**

```
 * @Gedmo\Sortable()
 * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
 * @var integer
 */
protected $position;
```

php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

give my

```
In AnnotationException.php line 54:

  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Sortable" in property Mea\TaskBundle\Entity\Task::$position does not exist,  
   or could not be auto-loaded.
```

Answer (score 1):

That class doesn't exist. I believe what you are looking for is [SortablePosition](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/lib/Gedmo/Mapping/Annotation/SortablePosition.php) or [SortableGroup](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/lib/Gedmo/Mapping/Annotation/SortableGroup.php).

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/sortable.md#sortable-entity-example).